# REST response with selective json properties from json

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I have an entity like

```
public class Pojo{
    int id;
    org.json.JSONObject json;
    /* other properties */
}
```

Now what I want to do is to send this `Pojo` object back as JSON BUT in a selective way so that an `admin` user has access to all properties and a `regular` user has selective access.

I can do that by using [Spring JSONView](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring) and creating different views for `admin` and a `regular` user. However, the problem which i am stuck at that how can i add selective properties for `admin`/`regular` user from `JSONObject`? The only possible way i could think of is to create a another Pojo to map that object and then use that object in response. But I want to make sure that there is no other way to approach this.

P.S: its a spring boot application

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it works with JsonObject but you can give this a try. Would be interesting to know if it works with "dynamic" objects.

https://github.com/Antibrumm/jackson-antpathfilter

(I'm the creator of that project)